# Implementing MongoDB in AWS EC2 Container Service

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops

I need to implement MongoDB in Amazon's AWS EC2 Container Service and I have no clue how to start with it, there's little or none documentation about it and I was wondering if anyone of you has already faced the same problem and maybe we can share some solutions.

Thanks in advance :)